# Cómo guardar un ArrayList de objeto

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un problema guardando ArrayList de objetos. He usado Gson para poder guardar pero algo no funciona bien. La idea es guardar ciertos datos en una activity y luego leerlos en otra activity.
Aquí va el método para guardar el archivo

```
public void guardar()
{
    ArrayList<Kardex>kar = new ArrayList<>();
    kar.add(new Kardex(nombre, observaciones, Integer.toString(kar.size()), category));

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonList = gson.toJson(kar);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("ListaX", jsonList);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Éste es el método que uso para leer el archivo

```
public void leer()
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String savedList = preferences.getString("ListaX", "");
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Kardex>>(){}.getType();
    ArrayList<Kardex> objects = gson.fromJson(savedList, type);

}
```

Me parece que el problema surge cuando intento leer el Gson, ya que al momento de ejecutar la activity se rompe y sale de la app.
En caso de no poder guardar en Gson podrían ayudarme a guardar estos datos de otra manera?

Comment: Mira el logcat y dinos el error que muestra alli cuando intentas hacerlo.

Comment: `01-01 10:24:16.434 20287-20305/xd.lotus.agil I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-01 10:24:16.441 20287-20305/xd.lotus.agil W/OpenGLRenderer: load: so=/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so
                                                               dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so" not found
01-01 10:24:16.441 20287-20305/xd.lotus.agil W/OpenGLRenderer: Initialize Binary Program Cache: Load Failed
01-01 10:24:16.441 20287-20305/xd.lotus.agil E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc` Me genera este Log